# How to use WCF fault contract globally without having to specify at operation level?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I need to return a fault of specific type from a WCF service so that the client can catch `FaultException<MyClass>`. In order to do this, as far as I know, only way out is to apply the `FaultContract(typeof(MyClass))` at the operation level. Is there any other way to do this at a global level? One place where I can add this contract to all operations in all services?

Comment: You can vote for adding this feature: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/343148/allow-faultcontractattribute-to-be-specified-on-a-servicecontract-interface

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF: Same Faultcontract on many methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392556/wcf-same-faultcontract-on-many-methods) Funny fact: Both has wrong marked answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you need to add it at every operation, however you can use tools like [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) that will re-write your code on compile so you could create an attribute that you put on a contract and have PostSharp add the correct `FaultContract` attribute on each `OperationContract`.

Answer (score 0):

Yea...I wish we can just globally define the default FaultException for the service level, then override for specific messages. I'm on a WSDL first project and the WCF WSDLs come out looking FUGLY!